# Convert String to Double - JAVA

Tags: java, string, double, jtextfield, jcombobox

```
private void jComboBox1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        // TODO add your handling code here:

        //9


        txtTot.setText(jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString());
        tot= Double.parseDouble(txtTot.getText());
        CMB= (Double)jComboBox1.getSelectedItem();
        Total2=tot+CMB;
        txtTot.setText(Double.toString(Total2));

    }
```

From the `ComboBox` I'm setting the `jtextfield` and the second line I'm taking the `string` from the `textfield` and trying to convert it into a `double`.

Error below:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Double
    at test.Test.jComboBox1ActionPerformed(Test.java:392)
    at test.Test.access$600(Test.java:18)
    at test.Test$7.actionPerformed(Test.java:134)
    at javax.swing.JComboBox.fireActionEvent(JComboBox.java:1258)
    at javax.swing.JComboBox.setSelectedItem(JComboBox.java:586)
    at javax.swing.JComboBox.setSelectedIndex(JComboBox.java:622)
```

Comment: That code doesn't result in that exception. Have you recompiled after your last change? What's on line 392 of Test.java?

Comment: It's the start of the combobox : private void jComboBox1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

Comment: You have to provide a complete code that generates the exception

Comment: Is your getselectedItem a numeric value ?

Comment: yes it is  double : 5.00

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me it seems like you are selecting a value from a combobox then trying to add them together to create a grand total, with the total being updated every time you select a new value from the combobox.

This seems to be working for me, Note I've taken the first line away because it interfered with the existing total.

```
tot= Double.parseDouble(txtTot.getText());
CMB = Double.parseDouble((String) jComboBox1.getSelectedItem());
Total2=tot+CMB;
txtTot.setText(Double.toString(Total2));
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to print the txtTot.getText () to the console and check whether it is in proper decimal format. Incorrect format could be the cause of error.